# Get URL Route Parameters javascript and add class to its submenu to make it active

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

I have this route parameters that will display the submenus base on each parameters.

Please help,

Like:

http://test.dev/admin

http://test.dev/admin/package

http://test.dev/admin/product

http://test.dev/panel

http://test.dev/panel/profile

http://test.dev/panel/account

and all the menus under panel and admin it should be display under its sub-menu.

I want to get the panel and admin parameter or any in the 1st parameter as basis for adding classes to my CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var url = window.location.pathname,
            urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");
        $('a').each(function() {
            if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
                var tab = $(this).data('main_menu');
                $(this).parents('li').addClass('menu-item-active');
                $(this).parents('div.tab-pane').addClass('show');
                $(this).parents('div.tab-pane').addClass('active');
                $('#' + tab).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What I am trying to get is the panel and admin parameter so that I can add classes to it.

Comment: Is `window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]` what you looking for?

Comment: @Hangindev got it!.. Thank you